# How to redirect HTTPS to HTTP using GCP load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, gcloud, google-cloud-load-balancer

This is a question on

how to redirect **https -> http**,

**NOT** http -> https.

We are using a Cisco router for our wifi login.  Our splash page is on our website, which is http.  The router requires http.  This works fine for android and windows, etc, but does not work for iOS and MacOS, which will will look for https and use it if possible.

The site is wordpress and the connection between the two load balancers and the VMs is http, so using $_SERVER['HTTPS'] wouldn't work, and using that or $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] - I believe may cause an infinite redirect on Apple OS's.

So, what I need is for the path `/wifi-login/` to be redirected to `http://` if it is `https`.  I think this needs to be done on the load balancer level.

Comment: The links you provided are irrelevant; neither service can provide https to http.
Can you think of a clever workaround?

Answer (score 0):

What I can think that we can try for this concern is to edit the created https Load balancer. Edit the frontend configuration for https traffic .Look for the "Protocol" section and change it from "HTTPS" to "HTTP." Changing frontend configuration to listen for http traffic it may redirect https to http.